# Definite integrals proof.

Tags: definite-integrals

I am reading this text and I don't get the proof:

[image]

I don't see how the FTC2 is applied a second time. Where did the second set of equations come from?

Where did the $u$ come from? And by "second time" do they mean "let's apply FTC2 to a completely different equation and show we get the same result?"

Answer (score 3):

You look at $F(g(b))-F(g(a))$ in two different ways.

- $F(g(b))-F(g(a))=F(g(x))|_{a}^{b}$
- $F(g(b))-F(g(a))=F(u)|_{g(a)}^{g(b)}$

Comment: I see, so "lets apply FTC2 a second time" doesn't mean applying FTC to the result of the first equation right? But just to a completely different equation?

Comment: Yes, you're right. They're not using FTC twice in a row on the same expression, they are using it on another function.